# Using static object in overloaded global new operator cause core dumped run time error

Tags: c++, new-operator

In this code I tired to simply know which object I forget to delete so I made a singleton with one static object to count the new allocated objects, but using this object inside global `new` function causes error, the same error occurs if I want to use standard objects like `cout`. What could be the cause of that error and what is the proper way to get the same effect?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

class Count_new { //singleton 

  std::vector<void*>count_v ; // to get "new" pointers
  Count_new(){}
  Count_new(const Count_new&);

public:
  void  count(void * m) {
    count_v.push_back(m);
  }

  static Count_new * instance(){
    static Count_new c ;
    return &c;
  }

  ~Count_new() 
  {
    unsigned int index = 0 ;
    while (index < count_v.size()) {
      if(count_v.at(index) != NULL) 
      std::cout << count_v.at(index) << " not deleted\n" ;
    }
  }
};

Count_new &c = *Count_new::instance();

void * operator new (size_t sz) throw (std::bad_alloc){
  void *m = malloc(sz);
  c.count(m); //produce Error core dumped
  return m;

}

class Obj{};

int main() {
  try {
    Obj *p1 = new Obj ;
    Obj *p2 = new Obj ;
  }catch(std::bad_alloc&b){
    std::cout << "Error in memory allocation:" << b.what()<< "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: mind that your static variable does not belong to the class definition (so it is not a common one for all class instances). It belongs to a method, so it's scope is that method....What exactly are you trying to achieve here...

Comment: @Pandrei Google for "Meyers singleton" - it's a good way to implement a singleton without hitting the "static initialisation order fiasco." Of course, if cna lead to a "static destruction order fiasco" if you're not careful.

Comment: Hint: replace tabs with spaces before posting on Stack Overflow, they mess up the code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're hitting endless recursion. You've replaced the global `::operator new` which is used by *everything* by default. This includes the allocation performed by the default allocators, such as the one `std::vector<T>` uses. So your call to `count` calls `push_back`, which needs to reallocate, which eventually calls `::operator new`, which calls `count`, which ...

If you want to keep this scheme, you'll have to write allocator which doesn't use `::operator new`, and then modify the type of `count_v` to use that allocator.

Oh and I'd drop the dynamic exception specification, they're deprecated since C++11.

Comment: Thanks, may be this is the second question to answer for me, but I am wondering if there is a dynamic array-like structures which can store the pointers and don't use new operator in their mechanism, just to avoid c-like code

Comment: @user3270926 No; by default, all `std` containers use the default allocator, which calls `:: operator new`. The way to customise is to write your own allocator. You need *some* dynamic allocation to store an unbounded number of objects. There is nothing bad about using `malloc` in your allocator, like you do in your `::operator new`.